# Can't convert from date time to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my question I am trying to solve:

> Create a report that the CompanyName and total number of orders by customer renamed as number of orders since December 31, 1996. Show number of Orders greater than 10

and I am using northwind database.

And my problem is that I can't convert `datetime` to `varchar`.

```
select c.CompanyName,
    count(o.OrderID) as NumOrders,
    convert(varchar(255),o.OrderDate)
from Customers c
join Orders o on(c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID)
where o.OrderDate >= '1996-12-31 00:00:00.000'
group by c.CompanyName,o.OrderDate
having count(o.OrderID) > 10
order by NumOrders desc;
```

Comment: What's the data type of the `OrderDate` column? If it's `date` then use `'1996-12-31'` in the comparison, if it's `datetime` then use `'1996-12-31T00:00:00.000'` instead.

Comment: Yes it was datetime and it worked thanks

Comment: Or you could just use `yyyyMMdd` which is unambiguous for *all* date and time data types.

Comment: I will try it. I really appreciate your answers thank you

Comment: Your code does not do what you state as the requirement. Is that the real issue here? Hint - your group by clause is wrong (along with columns in the select list).

Comment: Sorry for seeing this so late but yes there is a problem with having and orderdate i fixed it by removing orderdate. I am guessing orderdate acts as a unique key.